# Query to display the no. Of. 'L' present in employee name from employee table

Tags: sql

Query to display the no. Of. 'L' present in employee name from employee table

Comment: What database are you using? Microsoft, Oracle?

Comment: @Andrew Oracle........

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this :

**For case-insensitive matching**

```
SELECT REGEXP_COUNT(employeename, 'L', 1, 'i') NumberOfL,
  employeename FROM employee
```

**For case-sensitive matching**

```
SELECT REGEXP_COUNT(employeename, 'L', 1, 'c') NumberOfL, 
employeename FROM employee
```

Comment: I think that's only for Oracle, right?

Comment: @Narmatha, as now you specified that you are using Oracle, then I guess this answer is better than the other one.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the number of L's contained in each name:

```
SELECT LEN(employeename) - LEN(replace(employeename, 'L', '')) as NumberOfL, employeename FROM employee
```

This will take the length of the employee name and then subtract the length of that name with all occurrences of L replaced with empty strings.

For example if the name was Billy:

The length of Billy is 5. Replace all L's in his name with nothing and the length of what's left (Biy) is 3. Then we take the lengths of the two strings and perform the subtraction to get 5-3 = 2. Thus 2 L's in the string.

Comment: Add more information to explain your answer.